# How to do Translate Animation in android for app development

Tags: android, animation

I got a image ball which is to fall from above continuously on a time frame, the flow has to be continuous and the image should appear continuously as rain falling from above  and at certain speed, what is the best way of doing this.
what kind of animation would be helpful, Translate animation or using canvas..help me learn the usage of canvas in android.

How could i achieve this using canvas, any example would be helpful. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to take a look SurfaceView... As I have found previously SurfaceView gave me the freedom to do anything I wanted and avoid blocking the UI thread. As it has it's own thread, you can specify all kind of time frames and interactions. You can even calculate physics and collisions.  [HERE](http://www.droidnova.com/playing-with-graphics-in-android-part-i,147.html) is a great tutorial for getting you started.

Comment: @alin what do u mean by that could you please elaborate a little more..if u got time thanks though

Comment: thanks you alin, here the images are created on touch but how to make them fall from above on create or on load

Comment: Well, for example, make a ArrayList<BitmapToDraw> of all the bitmaps you want to draw. BitmapToDraw should be an object that contains Bitmap, XCoordonate and YCoordinate. On SurfaceView thread simply call a method that for each object BitmapToDraw from list, increments the YCoordinate with a value. Within onDraw you simply draw all objects from the list. To be more precise, I made a tutorial a while ago: http://www.androider.ro/tutorial-surfaceview-ul-si-oaia-care-voia-sa-alerge-3232  but it's in Romanian... but at the end there is a link to the source code of the project, you can use that.

Comment: thanks Alin will go through it.... thanks again.. may i have ur email if u wish to give it